# Hyper-V Ubuntu No internet in mobile data

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, hyper-v

I’m using ubuntu18.04 in Windows hyper-v.
To enable interner on ubuntu, I’ve created a network switch, say mySwitch. And then created a network bridge in windows, for mySwitch and home wifi.

Then, in ubuntu, I’ve changed IPV4 methode to manual, and then IP address is given same as of mySwitch

Now everything works fine.

But when i switch my home wifi to mobile hotspot, I’m not able to connect to internet in Ubuntu.
Tried changing IP address, IPV4 methode to DHCP, but nothing works